# Compact Riemann surfaces as holomorphically convex subsets of affine algebraic varieties

Tags: complex-geometry

Is there a simple argument (or a counterexample) to show that a holomorphically convex subset of an affine algebraic variety is a subvariety which is a compact Riemann surface?

Comment: There are problems with the question. ( 1) Affine varieties are already holomorphically convex. (2) Affine varieties do not contain any compact Riemann surfaces whatsoever.

Comment: @Donu: I believe you have answered the question...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps I should turn my comment into an "answer".
Affine algebraic varieties over $\mathbb{C}$ are Stein spaces. That is,
they are already holomorphically convex, and  points can be separated by global
holomorphic functions. The latter property implies that  affine varieties
can never contain compact Riemann surfaces.